# John Smith Esquire v. John Smith Attorney v. John Smith Attorney at Law

Tags: grammar, legalese

Which is the most proper way to sign a letter?  John Smith Esquire, John Smith Attorney or John Smith Attorney at Law.

Besides, does each of those categories denote different levels of engagement in the legal profession?

Comment: It might vary by region. What do other attorneys around you do?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma between the name and the title: `John Smith, Esq.`, `John Smith, Attorney`?

Answer (score 4):

*Esquire* is a form of address used in different ways in the U.K. and the U.S. In the US, it is only used as a professional designation for a lawyer. [Emily Post](http://www.emilypost.com/forms-of-address/titles/115-correct-use-of-esquire) wrote,

> “Esquire” is a professional designation in the legal arena—not a social designation. When you correspond with a lawyer, you have two choices: Write the person using a normal salutation (“Mr. Robert Jones” or “Ms. Cynthia Adams”) or put “Esquire” after the name, using the abbreviated form of “Esq.” (“Robert Jones, Esq.” or “Cynthia Adams, Esq.”) You would never use both the courtesy title of Mr. or Ms. and the professional designation of Esquire.

This applies to the US. In the UK, the term is [a bit broader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquire#Modern_British_usage):

> Many people in the United Kingdom no longer perceive any distinction between "Mr" and "Esquire" at all so that, in everyday usage, a distinction is very rarely intended.

So, if you are in the US, you can sign a letter *John Smith, Esquire* or *John Smith, Esq.* This is the form that I have seen most often in the US.

The terms *attorney* or *attorney at law* are names of one's actual position. For example, the editor of a magazine might have a byline that says "John Smith, Editor-in-Chief" and similarly a lawyer might use [John Smith, Attorney at Law](http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/writing-and-signature-requirements-for-a-valid-contract.html).

Since all of the terms are different (*Esquire* is a form of address, *attorney* is a position) they don't designate different levels of engagement in the profession. An *attorney at law* is an *attorney* who can [appear before the court](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/attorney+at+law).

Note that some lawyers *do* sign using "Esquire", so if the lawyers around you are doing so, feel free to do so as well.

To *address* a letter, use *Esquire* or *Esq.* in place of "Mr." or "Mrs." To *sign* a letter, use *Attorney* or *Attorney at Law* since they denote one's position rather than one's proper form of address. To sign with *Esquire* would likely be like signing a letter, "Mr. John Smith."

Comment: so what would the difference between *attorney* and *attorney at law* be?

Comment: @Jennifer: See paragraph 5 above.

Comment: I don't think "Esq." has been understood to have any "professional" significance at all in the UK for at least the past 40 years. You almost never see it now anyway, but when I was a *lot* younger it was often tacked on the end of men's names when banks, govt departments, utility companies, etc. wrote to you. Today it just comes across as a dated affectation on this side of the pond. Contrary to what many might think, Brits actually tend to avoid such designations nowadays.

Comment: ...check out the film credits of British and American movies over recent decades, and I'm sure it will be obvious that Hollywood is much more likely to have qualifications after many of the people who worked on the film. It's not that the Brits aren't qualified - it's just that they don't hanker to see such things broadcast to all and sundry.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "Esq." and "Esquire" in reference to attorneys or attorneys-at-law should be extinguished.  In the UK, attorneys were referred to as barristers, and "important" men or men in a high position were referred to as "Esq." and that could could and probably did include barristers. In high school nearly 45 years ago, we were taught that "esquire" is archaic and comes from England and means "Mr." or "Mister."  Defining "esquire" as "attorney" would imply that Esquire magazine is written only for attorneys, and it is not.  It is written for misters.  It is so disheartening that the use of "Esq." was resurrected from uncommon usage maybe about 20 years ago. I have worked for attorneys since high school to see the uncommon usage become popularized.  In my early days of working for attorneys, female attorneys were few and far between--only two in my small town.  After women's liberation, the number of female physicians, attorneys, etc., began to grow.  It is so disappointing to see the improper understanding of the definition of "Esq." to be passed on to female attorneys.  Only in the last five years or so have I started to see many attorneys (male and female) properly referred to as "J.D." (Doctor of Jurisprudence) since it is their degree and does mean attorney. If one insists on the use of "Esq.," then it should at least only be used to address someone else and never following your own name (if one is an attorney) and please never after a female's name.  To bury "Esq." in antiquity where it belongs has become a lifelong quest for me primarily because it does not mean attorney.  To all those who may read this, please help eradicate the improper and archaic usage of "Esq."  The common misunderstanding of the definition of a word should not be an excuse for it to be accepted as correct usage.

Comment: I wish people wouldn't downvote without explaining why.  I think this is a pretty reasonable comment about the usage of esquire.  I doubt it will be the "accepted" answer -- people want to know how Esquire **is** used, not how some curmudgeon thinks it **should** be used -- but Ruby Cube clearly has something to contribute here.